# limit output of dpkg-query -W to installed packages

Tags: dpkg

On a server running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I am trying to list installed kernels with the command:

```
 dpkg-query -W -f '${Package}\n' 'linux-image-[0-9]*'
```

which according to the manpage should list installed packages matching the pattern.
However the output of the command includes kernel versions which have already been removed.
How can I limit the output to kernels which are still installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html) on 20.04 says "*all packages matching the pattern*" which includes uninstalled packages. It does not claim to limit output to installed packages.

> ```
>    -W, --show [package-name-pattern...]
>       Just like the --list option this will list all packages matching
>       the given pattern. However the output can be customized using the
>       --showformat option.  The default output format gives one line per
>       matching package, each line having the name (extended with the
>       architecture qualifier for Multi-Arch same packages) and installed
>       version of the package, separated by a tab.
> ```

1. Add the Package state to your output

   `dpkg-query -W -f '${db:Status-Status} ${Package}\n' 'linux-image-[0-9]*'`
2. Filter the output using the package state field. All values except "not-installed" mean the package is at least partly installed.

   `dpkg-query -W -f '${db:Status-Status} ${Package}\n' 'linux-image-[0-9]*' | awk '$1 != "not-installed" {print}'`
3. Limit the output to the package name

   `dpkg-query -W -f '${db:Status-Status} ${Package}\n' 'linux-image-[0-9]*' | awk '$1 != "not-installed" {print $2}'`

Comment: Nice approach, but the grep pattern "installed" won't cut it. On one hand it *will* match uninstalled packages (Status "unknown ok not-installed") On the other hand it *won't* match some installed packages which sport status "install ok config-files". You'd need information about which keywords may actually appear in the Status field.

Comment: Edited to note that "installed" was a simple example. Your grep term may vary.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not happy with the "may vary" part. Isn't there a well-defined list of possible status values indicating that a package is installed from which to deduce a correct, non-varying grep pattern?

Comment: Sure there is. It's in the `dpkg` manpage. It's also in the `dpkg -l` output header.

Comment: Thanks, found it. I took the liberty of editing your answer to include the information I found, and will mark it as accepted once the edit has been approved.

Comment: Thanks for improving the answer, making it more useful for future users.